# Getting error when installing locust on windows-ERROR: No matching distribution found for cffi>=1.12.2;

Tags: python, pip, locust

Error receiving running pip install locust in windows
Long list of error appears I couldn't paste all here. THis is the tail end.

```
'C:\pip-standalone-pip-px9ol11r\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'Cip-build-env-l8j_yccl\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' Check the logs 
for full command output.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flask-cors to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flask-basicauth to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.     
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of click to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting click>=7.1.2
  Using cached click-8.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
  Using cached click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
  Using cached click-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
  Using cached click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flask to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting flask>=2.0.0
  Using cached Flask-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flask-cors to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flask-basicauth to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.     
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of click to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached Flask-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort 
this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort 
this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort 
this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of configargparse to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.      
Collecting ConfigArgParse>=1.0
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flask to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.5-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort 
this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.4.tar.gz (45 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.3.tar.gz (43 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.2.3.tar.gz (42 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of configargparse to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.      
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.2.2.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.2.1.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.2.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.1.tar.gz (41 kB)
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.0.1.tar.gz (41 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort 
this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.0.tar.gz (40 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of locust to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=1.12.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and sys_platform == "win32" (from gevent) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2.post2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0.post1, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cffi>=1.12.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and sys_platform == "win32"
```

Error receiving while installing pip
on windows using command pip install locust

Answer (score 0):

> Using cached locust-1.0-py3-none-any.whl (287 kB)

Thats a super old version of locust, not sure why your pip is trying to install that. Maybe try adding `-U` to make sure you get the latest version. Or use `pip3 install locust==2.4.0` to be explicit.

Comment: did tried both still having this error

Comment: NFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of locust to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=1.12.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and sys_platform == "win32" (from gevent) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2,15.0rc2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cffi>=1.12.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and sys_platform == "win32"

Comment: Sounds like you have another package installed with dependencies that arent compatible with Locust’s. this can be resolved using virtualenv, not sure if it works on windows though.

Comment: Or maybe the problem is that pip cannot find the correct versions of cffi. There are lots more versions than the ones you are seeing.